# Pgfplots polar axis: can I draw angle labels rotated as for smith charts?

Tags: pgfplots

[This is a question which came up on the `pgfplots` mailing list. Since it might be of general interest, I post it here.]

In `pgfplots`, the `smithcharts` library supports an option to draw the angular tick labels in a "sloped" way as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[yticklabel around circle]
    \end{smithchart}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The question is: (how) can I achieve the same for a `polaraxis`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}

\addplot  coordinates  {(2,2)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `smithchart` library is shipped with a style which does that for all `y` tick labels. However, `polaraxis` has the angular tick labels on the `x` axis, which means that the `smithchart` style does not apply. However, copying the `smithchart` style from the manual and substituting `y` by `x` does what you want:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    xtick align=center,
    xticklabel style={
            rotate=90,
            sloped like x axis={%
                execute for upside down={\tikzset{anchor=south west}},
                reset nontranslations=false
            },
            anchor=south east,
    }
]

\addplot  coordinates  {(2,2)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or, with a different alignment:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
    xtick align=center,
    xticklabel style={
            sloped like x axis={%
                execute for upside down={\tikzset{anchor=south}},
            },
            anchor=north,
    }
]

\addplot  coordinates  {(2,2)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]